# How to setup a conditional key=>value pair within php?

Tags: php

This is what I have:

```
'options' => array(
    'active' => (count($panels)>=2) ? false : NULL,
    'collapsible' => true,
    'icons' => null,
     'header' => "dt"
),
```

I assumed that the null on the value will be enough. However, the effect we wish will only occur, if and only if, all key=>value pair don't appear on the array.

How can I make this key=>value pair to appear:

```
'active' => false;
```

If count($panels)>=2 and to not appear at all, if that's not the case?

Is there an *clear*, *easy* and *understandable* way to achieve this, or should I play with array merges and stuff like that?

Please advice

Comment: Thank you all. Even with your help, I still can't figure it out, how can I setup that, using the framework (Yii) syntax. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141377/how-to-setup-a-conditional-key-value-pair-within-yii-widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it as follows:

```
$options = array(
    'collapsible' => true,
    'icons'       => null,
    'header'      => "dt"
);

if (count($panels) >= 2) {
    $options['active'] = false;
}
```

You'll obviously need to adapt this because your options array is contained within another.

Comment: that's exactly my issue. I have no clue how can I achieve that, on the widget configuration on my framework. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141377/how-to-setup-a-conditional-key-value-pair-within-yii-widget

Answer (score 1):

well... something like this!

```
$array = array(
    'options' => array(
        'collapsible' => true,
        'icons' => null,
         'header' => "dt"
    )
);
if (count($panels) >=2)
    $array['options']['active'] = false;
```

and i know you will read this and go 'yes i couldve figured that out' but there is no other way that i know of.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value to null still creates a key. If you don't want the key, then only set the value in the cases you want:

```
$array['options'] = array(
    ...
);
if (count($panels) >= 2) {
    $array['options']['active'] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141377/how-to-setup-a-conditional-key-value-pair-within-yii-widget/34803974#34803974)

```
'options' => array(
    //... other key/val pairs
) + (count($panels)>=2 ? array('active' => false) : array()),
```