# How to setup a conditional key=>value pair within Yii Widget?

Tags: php, yii

```
 $this->widget(
     'application.components.CJuiAccordionK',
                array(
                    'panels' => $panels,
                    'prices' => $packagesPrices,
                    'shortDescriptions' => $shortDescriptions,
                    'options' => array(
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'icons' => null,
                        'header' => "dt"
                    ),
                )
);
```

I need to place this key=>value pair on `'options'`, conditionally:

```
'active'=>false,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer my main question. I'm still clueless, how can we add a conditional key value pair on a Yii widget. However, the issue was solved by changing only the 'value' to the default one. Tried, NULL, and tried false, and tried true, no dice. On the jquery documentation we then can read that 0 is the default value so, if we do:

```
'options' => array(
                        'active' => (count($panels) === 1 ? 0 : false),
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'icons' => null,
                        'header' => "dt"
                    ),
```

We get the desired effect.

Just to share.

Answer (score 0):

By using [union operator ($a + $b)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) and ternary operator does the trick. Just pass an empty array if you want to add nothing. e.g:

```
'options' => array(
    //... other key/val pairs
) + (condition ? array('active' => false) : array()),
```